# Change language dynamically using androids multilanguage support?

Tags: android, multilingual

Is there are way to switch between different languages within an app using androids multilanguage support (`values-de` folder for german and `value-en` folder for english)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not really supported but possible by changing the Configuration object's "locale" field [[Google Groups Post](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg21287.html)]

```
Configuration c = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
c.locale = Locale.GERMAN;
getResources().updateConfiguration(c, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Note that this alone will only effect future strings, not ones already displayed on the screen. You'd want to do this from a different activity than your main one, then finish your main one and restart it.
This is hacky. See [Post from Hackborn](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg23182.html)

Comment: I will give it a try, when I get to this point in a few days. Thanks so far!

Comment: can I change it directly ?

Comment: @Kevin TeslaCoil with this I can run my APP with device language?

Comment: This works but it’s only temporary. If anything happens that changes the configuration (such as rotating the screen) then the changes get lost.