# Select a language from android app?

Tags: android, spinner

In my android app I need to do something like this: I have 5 languages. When app starts the user choose one of them from a spinner list. For each language there is a string.xml file. The question is: there is possible what I'm trying to do or not?

Comment: I think link in answer to that question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069008/multilanguage-app-best-way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [tutorial for localization](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/localization/index.html).
It's only only a few steps and well-explained.

Comment: That's nice, and well explained!

Answer (score 1):

A setup like that would be unneccessary as the Android system handles this. Having your different language xml files will suffice (make sure you name them correctly, see the link posted by Raz). Android picks out the right file based on the language selected by the user within the Android OS settings.

Comment: But he wants to change this himself everytime his app starts. Also he does not want change the System Locale. He wants to change the App Locale only.

Comment: That's not what he stated. He might not know about Android handling this.

Comment: Yes,Vishnu Haridas you right...this I want to do...I don't want that user to go from app to phone's settings to change the language

Comment: Yes, that's possible by programmatically changing the Locale inside your App. I think there are already 3 same answers here!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by changing the Locale of the application. There's a similar question in here, see [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html