# Language options in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application in which there is a drop down button,drop down is having 3 languages as option,on selecting a particular language,the entire application should change to that language.My application is ready with drop down button having 3 languages as its option,but i don't know how to change entire application in that particular chosen language.Please help me on this....

Comment: Perhaps you could create a separate layout for each language and replace it based on the selection?

Comment: Either this, or create a table which maps a language to a list of strings. When user selects different language you will need to pull strings from that table and manually set new text labels for all UI controls in code

Comment: Geesh, people start reading questions before casting your votes..

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to make a different String.xml in three language.
btw what type of data you want to show is that a static or get from other resource.

Answer (score 1):

Android is designed to support **localization**. You can achieve your aim by adding alternative String.xml files each stored in a locale-specific resource directory. There is plenty of information about localization in Android Developer's Dev Guide.

Here is the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Also a problem similar to yours was already discussed: [multilanguage app: best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069008/multilanguage-app-best-way)

Comment: I believe the question is not how to support changes in system locale, but rather how to allow the user to select a different language within the app. And that functionality is not greatly supported by the Android framework

Comment: Anton, you are right, but I think this is the case by design. If the user sets his phone to a preferred language, why should he want to switch the language of a single app to another language. In my opinion, the app shouldn't try to bypass android i18n mechanisms.

Answer (score -1):

```
Button s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ProfileLanguageButtton);

        s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings",


        "com.android.settings.LanguageSettings");
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```