# Switching xml string files

Tags: java, android

I am working on a bilingual app menu. I am currently at a dilemma on how I would be able to switch the languages easy. At first I thought I could use String.xml file to store the data passed out in English then later on Chinese and just switch xml string file for a chinese menu but the String.xml can only use a unique name ID.

Is there any other way of doing this? In which I can create another string array and call it instantly like String.xml?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I am always willing to listen and get better if what I put down was no appropriate.

Comment: Do you want to 'switch' the language dynamically if the user selects a preference, for example? Or do you want the language to be automatically set depending on the user's device settings?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069008/multilanguage-app-best-way

Comment: If you put that on the answer I would have marked that correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for [localization](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/). Here is tutorial on how to implement this in Android.

Comment: You got it. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I might make 2 (or more for more languages) apps that have the same function except for the fact that they are in different languages.

Comment: That sounds terrible no offense localization is the way to go.