# Dynamic Language change not working in Android app

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

**Please don't make it duplicate!**

I'm stuck in dynamic language change to `es-rUS` Spanish for US.
I put language translation into `values-es-rUS` but it couldn't help me.
If I put the same translation into `values-es` folder and accessing it dynamically through `es` then it works fine but when I put translation into `values-es-rUS` and accessing it dynamically through `es-rUS`, then its not working.

I went through following posts:

1. [Change language dynamically using androids multilanguage support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639078/change-language-dynamically-using-androids-multilanguage-support)
2. [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)
3. [How to change language of app when user selects language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908289/how-change-language-of-app-on-user-select-language)