# How to use Android Assets with multiple languages?

Tags: android, assets

I am using **Assets** files as help files in my app and have well over a dozen.  I am porting the app to multiple languages.  Where do the alternative language asset files go?

I am already using the "res/values" directories for language files (values, values-es, etc) for use within the app.  I thought the "**Assets**" directory was for help files and items like that.

I am trying to NOT muddy my values folders with the many help files that I am including and was using "activity.getAssets().open( file )" to read the files.

Also, some of these "**Asset**" files are different language pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language dynamically using androids multilanguage support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639078/change-language-dynamically-using-androids-multilanguage-support)

Answer (score 2):

For the voice recognition in my app (using [Vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/android)) I have defined the specific asset folder as resource string.
I.e. `values\strings.xml` contains:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="language_directory">vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15</string>
    ...
```

and `values-de-rDE\strings.xml` contains:

```xml
<resources>
    <string name="language_directory">vosk-model-small-de-0.15</string>
    ...
```

So I can access the asset directory via

```
val assets = Assets(activity)
val assetDir = assets.syncAssets()
val modelDir = activity.getString(R.string.language_directory)

recognitionListener.model = Model("$assetDir/$modelDir")
```

This way the correct directory is always chosen based in the active locale.

In my case, those are located at `models\src\main\assets\sync\<language_directory>`

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the files in /res instead of /assets? This has built in support for multiple languages, there is an easy to follow guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Basically, if your original text is in /res/values/strings.xml, for example, you would put your translations in /res/values-{ISO LANGUAGE CODE}/strings.xml

For example, your French translation would be in /res/values-fr/strings.xml.

Android will pick the appropriate translation file according to the locale of the user's phone.

There are some good explanations of the other differences between /res and /assets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories).

Comment: While I could do this, it would muddy the values folders with these raw files.  And some of the files are pictures.

Comment: For the pictures, you can do the same with res/drawable, eg res/drawable-fr. But the assets folder doesn't support this, so if you want to put the help files in there, you will have to select the correct files manually.

Answer (score -1):

Make folder in assets: 
 1. htmlpagesNL
 2. htmlpagesUS

Copy file from htmlpagesNL and paste to htmlpagesUS and Translate

Use url inside Nl string file:
file:///android_asset/htmlpagesNL for NL translation
Use url inside Us string file:
file:///android_asset/htmlpagesUS for US translation

Support different languages
[Support different languages and cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages?authuser=1)