# how to convert whole app language from English to German on button click in Android?

Tags: android

guys... I am stuck with problem after app developed. Now We have a new requirement to change whole application language if user selects the German language. So how to handle this?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4640910/5132804)?

Comment: Have you dig a google ? You can find many solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Better to delete question due to duplicate question, otherwise get negative  rating.

Comment: Pelocho Yes, I tried this. But didn't work with me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.setLocale(new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase()); // API 17+ only.
// Use conf.locale = new Locale(...) if targeting lower versions
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

For more info check this link : 
[Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android)